# Convert from NTSF to UEFI Questions

Tags: boot

I'm having so many problems Booting my Windows 10 PRO system that I wonder if I should convert it to UEFI.

1. I have a DZ68BC motherboard that I'd like to convert. Will it work with UEFI?
2. I use a SSD for my C: boot drive. Can you convert NTFS to UEFI on it?
3. Can I convert  my USB and HDD from NTFS to UEFI or do I need too?
4. Will my DVD and Blue-ray drives still work.
5. Will UEFI bypass the Intel boot menu (that I can change with F2, F8, F10)entirely.

Last but not least will I have to fix my boot problem before converting to GTP?

Comment: Since you do not qualify the exact problems you’re facing, it’s not possible to tell whether switching to UEFI could change anything.

Comment: UEFI is a replacement for BIOS, I.e. the system firmware. It has nothing to do with disk formats such as NTFS.

Comment: As others have noted: NTFS and UEFI are not versions of the same type of thing, they are two different types of things. You do not convert from one to the other.